# Conservation of information in expanding universe

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmology, entropy, information, unitarity

As the observable universe expands the amount of information is increasing, at least locally. How is this compatible with the conservation of information in quantum mechanics?

Comment: Isn't the observable universe *shrinking* due to expansion?

Comment: This may be of help:  https://van.physics.illinois.edu/QA/listing.php?id=24045